# Does the Google ML barcode scanner for Android have a mechanism to force only scan the EAN-13 barcodes

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I've created a bar code scanner in android with google ml bar code scanner, but when i scan this bar code

[image: test barcode]

this bar code is scanning as `UPC-A`. So the output will be `019100219281`,
but when I scanned it with iOS device it scans as `EAN-13` and returned `0019100219281`. Its the correct value that I want.
And I tried a barcode scanner site to scan same bar code in `UPC-A` [link](https://products.aspose.app/barcode/recognize/upc) and `EAN-13`
[link](https://products.aspose.app/barcode/recognize/ean) and they returned different values

So what happens is that ml barcode scanner is detecting this as `UPC-A`, I need to force scanner to detect only `EAN-13`.

I've tried

```
val options = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_13)
                            .build()
val barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(options)
```

but its not working

Comment: Both use the same encoding of bars & spaces, so it depends on the context of usage: https://www.barcodestalk.com/learn-about-barcodes/resources/what-difference-between-upc-and-ean

Comment: Even if you don't have the settings you want, as mentioned in the article by Morrison Chang in the comments, when you receive a UPC-A barcode, just insert a `0` at the beginning of the data to convert it to EAN-13. Therefore, the application should handle it as such is better.